# Query does not use composite index - why?

Tags: oracle, query-optimization

I have a query

```
select a.id,
       a.code,
       h.history_id
from a
join h
  on h.object_id = a.id
and h.level = 'Level1'
and h.class_id in ('class1', 'class2');
```

And its execution plan:

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation                     | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost   | Time     |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |       |   340 |108889 | 794224 | 00:00:32 |
    |  *1 |  HASH JOIN                    |       |   340 |108889 | 794224 | 00:00:32 |
    |   2 |   TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL   |     a |   340 | 39314 |      2 | 00:00:01 |
    |   3 |   PARTITION RANGE ALL         |       | 274564| 54855 |  69422 | 00:00:32 |
    |  *4 |    TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL  |     h | 274564| 54855 |  69422 | 00:01:14 |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

*1 - access("a"."id" = "h"."object_id")
*4 - storage ("h"."level" = 'Level1' and ("h"."class_id" = 'class1' or "h"."class_id" = 'class2'))
*4 - filter ("h"."level" = 'Level1' and ("h"."class_id" = 'class1' or "h"."class_id" = 'class2'))
```

Also there are indexes on tables - on table a(id) and composite index on table h(object_id, level, class_id). 
Statistics also was gathered.

Table a consist about 340 records and table h is about 1 billion records.
The result query returns about 200 rows

Although all columns from index for table h are used in join condition, by the plan there is not access predicate on columns level and class_id.
I don't understand this solution.

I want to at least h.level to be in access predicate.
It there any solutions for this? Or some kind of query rewrite?

Comment: Are you sure your preferred access would actually be more efficient? The optimiser is usually (though not always) pretty good at deciding the best way to do things - so why do you think it's wrong in this instance? How selective is the index on `h`, down to `level`?

Comment: You can do a bit of testing and get more information from it. For example: in the `SELECT` clause, remove `h.history_id` and run the query again, and look at the plan. Does it run faster? Does it use the index? It **should** use the index, since all the columns referenced in the query (from table `h`) are now in the index. If the query doesn't run any faster, that may mean that accessing the table (1 billion rows) is pretty much the same as accessing the index (also 1 billion rows), so there is no benefit from using it in the original query.

Comment: If the new query doesn't use the index, that means that there are other issues which need to be figured out.

Comment: +1 for both of these comments. The optimizer will use the index if it believes the index is more efficient. Unless you do the work of actually proving that it is more efficient, you are assuming that the index will always be faster, which might not be true depending on the structure and volume of your data. Please also check to see if the OPTIMIZER_INDEX_COST_ADJ parameter has been changed. If that parameter is changed, it essentially tells the optimizer to choose (or ignore) indexes more often. If that parameter has been changed, the optimizer might not be using the index for that reason

Comment: The crutial point is, how many row return this query: `select count(*) from h where h.level = 'Level1' and h.class_id in ('class1', 'class2')`. The optimize thinks it will be `274.564` rows. Thus 1) if the number of the rows is such high, you will *never want to use an index access* as it will take 1/2 hour or so); 2) If the number of the rows is much lower (comparable to the 300 from `A`), you can profit from index and you also know where the problem is - incorrect cardinality estimation on the filter on `H`.

Comment: Also using `LEVEL` as a column name can lead to problems as it is [reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm)

Comment: What @MarmiteBomber is trying to tell index access requires random acces disk I/O which is slow avg 4-8 ms on standard HDD's for every index acces vs one read which requires 1 random acces disk I/O avg 4-8 ms on standard HDD's and reads at 80-160 Mb/s on standard HDD's to get the data (FULL TABLE scan)....meaning (274564 rows * 4 ms) = 1098256 ms  which is 18.3042667 minutes.. But it might be even slower when B-tree indexing is used for larger tables it can be 3 or 4 random access seeks per index to get the correct data.

Comment: Such specific questions requires to post the Oracle version. I guess you are on 11g or older, as in 12.2 I observe index access (either direct or index skip scan).

Comment: On what key the table `H` is partitioned?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the statement, that the result of the query has only 200 rows, the index should be used.

With synthetic data (the most simple case, `OBJECT_ID` is unique in table `H`) you should see this execution plan

```
Plan hash value: 3146900768

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | Reads  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |      |      1 |        |    200 |00:00:00.04 |      40 |      4 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                |      |      1 |      2 |    200 |00:00:00.03 |      40 |      4 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS               |      |      1 |    340 |    200 |00:00:00.02 |      36 |      3 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL         | A    |      1 |    340 |    340 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |      0 |
|*  4 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | HIX  |    340 |      1 |    200 |00:00:00.02 |      33 |      3 |
|   5 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| H    |    200 |      1 |    200 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |      1 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - access("H"."OBJECT_ID"="A"."ID" AND "H"."LEVEL_ID"='Level1')
       filter(("H"."CLASS_ID"='class1' OR "H"."CLASS_ID"='class2'))
```

So please check your Oracle version (I'm on 12.1)

Verify if the statistics are accurate.

Check the system statistics.

Check if your Oracle CBO parameters are fine.